# using if statements in tableau on a contains function

Tags: if-statement, contains, tableau-api

Say I have city populations for each state / city in the united states. I want to mark each city with over 2 million population as a big city. then if a state contains a "big city", i want to mark that state as a "big state". I made a calculated field:

if Pop>2000000 then "big city" else "small city" end
This works fine.

Now when I try to make a calculated field for state I tried this:

if contains([big city],"big") then "big state" else "small state" end

This almost works, but I get multiple values for each state when I only want 1 value, either big state or small state. How do I stop tableau from creating multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that with an approach involving two calculated fields.

Assuming that your big_city, small_city calculation is a calculated field named `City_Size`

Now, the First Calculated field will assign a 1 or 0 to each row, depeding upon the value of `City_Size`. Name it as `is_big_state`

```
if City_Size = 'big' then
    1
else
    0
end
```

Now use this calculated field into another calculation, termed as `State_type`

```
IIF(Max(City_Size) = 1, "Big State", "Small State")
```

**Edit : You may combine both of them into one :**

```
IIF(Max(iif(City_Size = 'big', 1, 0)) = 1, "Big State", "Small State")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `state` set to `"small state"` by default.

When you check for city population, set the `state` to `"big state"` if you find a `"big city"`.

```
if Pop > 2000000
    then "big city"
         "big state"
else
    "small city"
```

Comment: Hi Bruce thanks for the reply. I do not believe your equation works in tableau, there is a logical error after your "then" statement (you cannot set big city and big state together like that). Also, this is a simple version of a more complex problem, so I can't use work arounds :)

Comment: *`if contains([big city],"big") then "big state" else "small state"`* - How about removing `else "small state"` from your code? That way big states won't get set to big **and** small states.

Comment: because I also want to label the states that dont have big cities... and my real code is a little more complex anyways, it's more like if value>7 then x elseif value >4 then y else z... so I'm just trying to get the logic in place to develop other things :)